# How to change profile link in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

By default, a request to a root URL in a Spring Boot application will return a mapping like

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/hal+json

{ "_links" : {
    "orders" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/alps"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm using the root URL to return the home page, or index of the application.  I'd still like to use the profile link but all I get is the homepage.  Is there any way I can still access it?

I tried requesting with a specific content type but it did not change anything.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/hal+json" localhost:8080 -v
```

and

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/hal+json" localhost:8080 -v
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case because of a Spring Boot application, but because you use Spring Data REST, which provides this endpoint. To change the base url of the REST repositories, you can add the property `spring.data.rest.base-uri=/api` (note, that this changes the path of all REST endpoints of Spring Data REST, not only the root).

However, it should also work, if you define your homepage on the root context and then specify the content type of the GET request. So, if you have defined an HTML page on the root context and add the content type `text/html`, you should get your homepage instead of the REST resource overview.

Comment: Actually what is happening is that I get the homepage no matter what, and I'm not sure how to see the resource overview.  See updated answer

Comment: You're right, i just tried it. I think the problem is, that Spring Data REST doesn't specify an explicit "Produces" Content-Type on the root controller, so the request with the application/hal+json doesn't get mapped to the controller (i guess, it loads the homepage because of the order of the mappings). In that case the only solution seems to change the base URI for the repositories.